# Reduce QGIS project needed PostgreSQL connections

Tags: qgis, postgresql, connection

I have a QGIS project, based on data from a PostgreSQL database. The project should be used by a lot people from my company. In a performance test I noticed, that every person, who opens the project block 3-5 connections to the database.

Is there any possibility to reduce the number of connections, which are blocked from the project?

The parameters, which I use for the database connection in QGIS.

```
connections\selected=QGIS
connections\qgis\service=
connections\qgis\host=123.45.67.89
connections\qgis\port=4125
connections\qgis\database=QGIS
connections\qgis\username=QGIS
connections\qgis\password=qgis
connections\qgis\authcfg=
connections\qgis\publicOnly=false
connections\qgis\geometryColumnsOnly=false
connections\qgis\dontResolveType=false
connections\qgis\allowGeometrylessTables=false
connections\qgis\sslmode=SslDisable
connections\qgis\saveUsername=true
connections\qgis\savePassword=true
connections\qgis\estimatedMetadata=false
connections\qgis\projectsInDatabase=false
```

Comment: just increase the number of connections your server will accept - none of them are doing much most of the time

Comment: I already did this, but I thought there is might be a possibility to reduce the connections in the project.

Comment: I'm not the expert in this area. We also got the issue in our infrastructure. I think my colleagues where talking about differences about layers from browser, the use of DBManager (in Python) which doesn't manage the same way. I don't know more.

Comment: "lot of people" (can give a number?) we have 3000 users on our postgis server no issues with performance but it is setup to handle large volumes of users (load balancer etc)